# How to add "About" tab on Mac

Tags: java, macos

On a Mac, there is a button on the screen menu bar that is the name of an application. For example, for terminal, there is a button at the top of the screen labeled **Terminal**. When you click it, there is a options that says **About Terminal**. When this is clicked, it shows information about the application. Here is a picture:

[image: About tab for Terminal]

How can I add this to my application in Java? When I do this now, this is what shows up:
[image: About tab for Java Application]

As you can see, it shows the Java version etc. Is there a way to change this into a more professional format?

Comment: Perhaps the [Packaging tool added to Java 16](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/392) might help. That mentions metadata including version number. And it creates a folder fir icons where I imagine you could place an app icon to be picked up by the About window automatically. All speculation on my part; I have not used this tool.

Comment: I checked this tool out, and it essentially does the same things as the javapackager tool. I can add the Icon and version of the application, but I was wondering more of a  customizable part that doesn't just show the app icon, name, and version. But that would be enough... Thank you I will definitely try this.

Comment: Just tested and it worked like magic. Thank you!

Comment: Please post an Answer to your own Question, to document the solution.

Comment: FYI, Apple years ago gave guidance asking developers to keep the *About* box small and simple. If you have more to share with users, I suggest providing a Help feature or find some other avenue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I've solved the problem. It was a simple mistake, when I packaged it together using a packager it worked fine. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

If your Window extends `JFrame`, just use the `setIconImage` or `setIconImages` method to set your icon.

From the corresponding JavaDoc:

> Sets the image to be displayed as the icon for this window.

The other information is read from the executable metadata. If you run your app using Java directly, you can't change it. For my applications, I generate an executable file using Install4J, where the installer adds the metadata to the generated executable.